# Unable to resolve Inflate method

Tags: java, android, android-inflate

So I am trying to inflate a layout in my activity but I keep getting this error:

> Cannot resolve method 'inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, null)'

Here my Code:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
        R.layout.item_list, parent, null
    ));
}
```

Was I missing something?

Comment: The three-argument `inflate` overrides [expect a `boolean` as the third parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)). What do you intend `null` to do here? When in doubt: remove the `, null`.

Comment: oke,thanks for your answer,the message error gone ^^

Comment: Check the documentation that I linked to, figure out what you want to do and then decide based on that. It feels like right now you're just [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way.

First import the fragment.

```
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
```

then extand from DialogFragment like this `extends DialogFragment`

and then overide the `onCreateView`

```
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
                               container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR-FRAGMENT-NAME, container, false);

    //to access xml elements you use view.findviewbyid ...

    return view;
  }
```